# Is it possible to add key value pairs to SharedPreference file of apk from terminal before installing?

Tags: android, react-native

I don't know much about Android development and basically do ReactNative. I want to test the scenario of how MDM setup is done in my local. Is it possible to update the SharedPreference file from terminal before app is installed in device.

Answer (score 0):

It is an XML file under /data/data/your.app.package.name/shared_prefs, and the file name is your.app.package.name_preferences.xml. It is really easy to modify the preferences when you figure out that the content is just a key-value map.
You need to rooted device to update the xml else permission will be denied.

Comment: Will this file even exist even before apk is installed?

Comment: No it does not exist.